# How do I check what the source is in an imageview?

Tags: android, imageview

I need to check on a button click if there is a drawing associated with the list or if its "invisible". I am doing the check by seeing if the source of the drawing is @drawable/invisible or something else. If its something else then change it to invisible, if invisible then change it to a color etc...

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View listview, int position,
                long arg3) {
            ImageView pincolor=(ImageView) listview.findViewById(R.id.ivimtrackingpin);
           // here is where I want to check what the "source" is
            if(pincolor.getResources().equals(R.drawable.invisible)
             //do stuff
            else 
                pincolor.setImageresource(R.drawable.invisible)

        }
    });
```

I don't want to just do setvisibility =invisible because there are different colors that each list can be and the switch function will go inside the if part. What method do I use to determine the imageviews source?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can make use of the ImageView's [getDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable%28%29) Method.

```
/**
* Return the view's drawable, or null if no drawable has been assigned.
*/
public Drawable getDrawable ()
```

like this:

```
ImageView pincolor=(ImageView) listview.findViewById(R.id.ivimtrackingpin);
Drawable drawable = pincolor.getDrawable();
if(drawable  != null) {
    //do stuff with the drawable
} else {
    pincolor.setImageresource(R.drawable.invisible)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you if the view is invisible:

```
pincolor.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE
```